# SOQL Query for Date = THISYEAR

Tags: soql

I'm trying to write a SOQL query that uses " WHERE Date__c = THISYEAR() " but that isn't working... I think what i'd need to do is create a variable:

```
Integer currentyear = System.Today().year()
```

however I feel like that isn't optimal... what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) like in the below query

```
SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = THIS_YEAR
```

**`THIS_YEAR` :** Starts 00:00:00 on January 1 of the current year and continues through the end of December 31 of the current year.